# Creating multiuser SQL Server Database using Visual Studio on a shared location

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, multi-user

I have developed a windows form application with `c#` which uses a shared `MS Access` file (back-end file) as database and users connect via front-end files.

Now I am trying to implement a different approach using `SQL Server`.

I want to have a database located in a shared folder that applications would connect automatically.

Please share your ideas about the best way to implement the database.

Should I create a database project or just add a service-based database to the form application project?

If both are applicable which one is more prestigious solution?

Since I am an amateur in database programming please share any other ideas that includes `SQL Server`.

Please notice that I don't have `SQL Server Management Studio` and I want to know if I can perform this using only `Visual Studio 2012`.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't work like MS-Access.  There IS only file database file, and only 1 SQL Server can access it.  Your code will communicate with the server, not directly with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications. [Introduction to Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Step-by-step walkthrough shows how to bind POCO types to Window Forms (WinForms) controls. [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682076(v=vs.113).aspx)

Step-by-step walkthrough provide an introduction to Code First development targeting a new database. [Entity Framework Code First to a New Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)